# How do I print the results of the code below into 2 separate lines of sequences?

Tags: java, for-loop, format, printf, println

I'm currently on some basic exercises on HackerRank (It's my 3rd day with Java). I just finished writing the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int seriesInput = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int q = 0; q < seriesInput; q++) {
            int inputA = scanner.nextInt();
            int inputB = scanner.nextInt();
            int inputN = scanner.nextInt();
            double s0 = inputA + Math.pow(2, 0) * inputB;
            int s2 = (int) s0;
            System.out.print(s2 + " ");
            for (int i = 1; i < inputN; i++) {        
                s0 += Math.pow(2, i) * inputB;
                int s1 = (int) s0;
                System.out.print(s1 + " ");
      }  System.out.println();
    } scanner.close();
  }  
}
```

Comment: Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: I used System.out.print() but it returns everything on the same line without space (2614306212625451010222046814265098) . I expect it to look like this (First line: 2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046; Second line: 8 14 26 50 98).

Comment: `System.out.println` is short for "print line", so it will print the text and the insert a new line at the end. `System.out.print` will print text, but not move to a new line. If you need a space after the what you've printed, print a space `System.out.print(s2 + " ")` for example

Comment: In addition to replacing the existing `System.out.println(…)` with `System.out.print(… + " ")` you’ll have to add a `System.out.println();` after the inner loop to terminate the line.

Comment: "*without space*" -> then you must print a space (and to be more *exact*, print it before printing each value but the first one [i == 1]; or print it after each value but the last one [i == inputN-1])

Comment: Please have a look at [TOUR] and [ASK]

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int seriesInput = scanner.nextInt();
    
        for (int q = 0; q < seriesInput; q++) {
            int inputA = scanner.nextInt();
            int inputB = scanner.nextInt();
            int inputN = scanner.nextInt();
            double s0 = inputA + Math.pow(2, 0) * inputB;
            int s2 = (int) s0;
            System.out.print(s2 + " ");

            for (int i = 1; i < inputN; i++) {        
                s0 += Math.pow(2, i) * inputB;
                int s1 = (int) s0;
                System.out.print(s1 + " ");
            } System.out.println();
        } scanner.close();
    }
}
```

This is my full answer to the Java Loops II question on HackerRank. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).